# Response time on inputstream

Tags: android, inputstream, http-get, urlconnection, instagram-api

When I try to make a get request on Instagram, on an average, I get a delay of 250 ms. The same call on iOS gets around 50 ms. I tried StringBuilder, HttpGet with HttpResponse(gives the worst delay of 350 ms).

```
        StringBuilder response = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.connect();
        long start2 = System.currentTimeMillis();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( urlConnection.getInputStream()));
        Log.e("Response Time", "Reader ends = " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start2));
        char[] buf = new char[2048];
        int charsRead;
        while((charsRead = reader.read(buf, 0, 2048)) > 0) {
            response.append(buf, 0, charsRead);
        }
        reader.close();
        urlConnection.close();
```

Could anyone suggest me how can I decrease the delay?

Comment: What is variable `response`?  And how much data is transferred?  And can you predict in advance (at least a bound on) how much data will be transferred?

Comment: Where is the delay introduced? Is it connection establishment, actual request or the data transfer of data? How much data is transferred?

Comment: We cannot help you if you provide inaccurate information.  You have edited your question to add a declaration of `response` as a `String`, but `String` does not have an `append()` method such as your code invokes on `response`.

Comment: @dhke Delay is on urlConnection.getInputStream(). the get method is (https://)api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN , the response is JSON

Comment: @Erturr Hmm. That is before any data is read, i.e. during the socket connection and HTTP request phase. You might try with setting up a raw `SSLSocket` to port `443` of the same server and see if the delay is actually introduced by TLS negotation.

Comment: @JohnBollinger response is a empty stringbuilder, i updated my code. The data is close to 64kb data is transferring to phone. Sorry for the misread code.

Comment: @dhke Thanks for the response, I'll let you know when it's done.

Comment: Are you *sure* that the delay occurs in `getInputStream()`?  That's about the least likely place I can see in your code.  If the TLS negotiation were the problem then I would expect the delay to be in the `connect()`, and if it were in the server actually delivering data then I would expect it to be in the first `read()`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I have updated my code. The output is : E/Response Time﹕ Reader ends = 575

Comment: @dhke Can you provide a piece of code for `SSLSocket` ?

Comment: @Erturr use something like https://gist.github.com/dhke/863c922e37979d9dba60. This only tries to connect to instagram using TLS, nothing else. If the delay is not there with this piece, you have more or less eliminated the TLS setup as a problem.